# What the sign ' | ' stand for?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation, divisibility

Going through a proof of a theorem, I encountered the following statement:

> $e\mid a/d$, $e\mid b/d$
>
> Then, $a/d = ex$, $b/d = ey$ where $x,y$ belongs to $\mathbb{Z}$.

However, my question not about the proof of the theorem.

My question is, what does the sign ' $\mid$ ' mean?

Comment: $\mid$ is used to mean a lot of different things, so we'll need some more context.

Comment: One writes $m | n$ if $m$ is a divisor of $n$.

Comment: From the notation you might expect that $a|b$ means that $\dfrac ab$ is an integer, but actually it means that $\dfrac ba$ is an integer.

Answer (score 3):

The symbol $\mid$ means "divides" (in this context, at least).  That is, if $a$ and $b$ are integers then $a\mid b$ (read "$a$ divides $b$") means that there exists an integer $c$ such that $b=ac$.  Except in the case $a=b=0$, this just means that $b/a$ is an integer.  (More generally, you can make the same definition for elements of any ring.)

Comment: yeah, i also accept the ans . Thanks .